# how to change all elements id in div child

Tags: javascript

How I can change and add something to all ids in div child elements that have something like `bi_` in his first. like this example:

```
<script>
    var opts = '1';
    $('.mm > #bi_name').attr('id', 'bi_name_'+opts);
    $('.mm > #bi_email').attr('id', 'bi_email_'+opts);
    $('.mm > #bi_expire').attr('id', 'bi_expire_'+opts);

    $('.ss > #bi_ohhh').attr('id', 'bi_ohhh_'+opts);
    $('.ss > #bi_bala').attr('id', 'bi_bala_'+opts);
    $('.ss > #bi_ola').attr('id', 'bi_ola_'+opts);

    .....

</script>

<div id="lol" class="mm">

    <!-----I want to change all id below----->

    <div id="profile"> 
                <div class="about text-center">
                    <h1 id="bi_name">Banned player name</h1>    //change and this id="bi_name" to id="bi_name_1"
                </div>
                <ul class="personal-info">
                    <li><label><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Email</label><span id="bi_email">EMAIL</span></li> //change and this id="bi_email" to id="bi_email_1"
                    <li><label><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Expire Time</label>
                        <span>
                            <a href="" id="bi_expire" data-original-title="Select Date of ban expire">EXPIRE TIME</a> //change and this id="bi_expire" to id="bi_expire_1"
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </div> 
    <div id="content" class="ss">
        .....
    </div> 
    <div id="gallery" class="gg">
        ....
    </div> 

    <!-----I want to change all id above----->

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use target all the elements using [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) then use  [`.attr(attributeName, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to set the `id`

```
var opts = '1';
$('.mm [id^=bi_]').attr('id', function(_, val){
    return val + '_' + opts;
});
```

Comment: hmm sorry but not work

Comment: with `find` its worked but with you code no

Comment: `$('.mm').find('[id^="bi_"]').attr("id", (_, oldVal) => oldVal + "_" + opts)`

Comment: Sorry my mistake :D Worked. thank you.